# Render Custom Fields in Admin edit view

Tags: custom-component, custom-field, joomla-4

I want to add custom fields to my component.  My admin edit view uses bootstrap tabs:

```
<?php echo HTMLHelper::_('uitab.startTabSet', 'myTab', array('active' => 'general')); ?>

<?php echo HTMLHelper::_('uitab.addTab', 'myTab', 'general', Text::_('COM_MYCOMP_TITLE', true)); ?>
```

Then I render the fieldset:

```
<?php echo $this->form->renderFieldset('general'); ?>
```

Now I want to render my custom fields before the endTabSet using:

```
<?php $this->ignore_fieldsets = array('general'); ?>
<?php echo LayoutHelper::render('joomla.edit.params', $this); ?>
```

But this gives me an error of Notice: Undefined index: Joomla\CMS\HTML\Helpers\Bootstrap::startTabSet.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If it is your own component you don't really need to use custom fields. In your form xml file you can define a field set, as for general, and then in your edit template add a new tab, render the field set and then close the tab. In fact with a lot of field sets you can just cycle through them. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but perhaps I didn't make this question clear enough.  Yes it is my component but I want to provide the "admin user" of the component to be able to "add" their own custom fields.  So currently I have the custom fields able to be added to the component and then when a new record is added, then custom field is displayed BUT I get this error about the undefined index.  If you have a look at the standard User Management system, the administrator of the site can add extra fields to the user record through Custom Fields (com_fields) so user adds data to these fields.